# How to find duplicate records in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to write a query to find duplicate rows in **Codegigniter** but its not working.
My code (Model)

```
$this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->from('myTable sr');
      $this->db->join('table2 s','sr.st_id=s.st_id'); 
      if($conn!='')
      {
          $this->db->where($conn);
      }
      if($identity!='')
      {
          $where = "(s.student_id = '$identity' OR s.name LIKE '%$identity%')";
          $this->db->where($where);
      }
      if($duplicate != '')
      {
        $this->db->having('COUNT("sr.st_id")>1');          
      }
      if($limit_row!='')
      {
          $this->db->limit($limit_row,$starting);
      }
      $query = $this->db->get();
      var_dump($this->db->last_query($query));exit;
      return $query->result_array();
```

Only returns first record
Duplicate data is in myTable and I want to find find those duplicates

Comment: Please provide a data. Without it, we can not check query.

Comment: this statement is not clear and has a bug => $this->db->join('table2 s','sr.st_id=s.st_id'); rs','rs.resultState_id=sr.result_state');

Comment: I edited the code, the goal is to how to find duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username, email, COUNT(*)
FROM users
GROUP BY username, email
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Group and find it

Comment: It does skip duplicate record, but I want to find the duplicate one.Mona Bishnoi

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('myTable sr');
$this->db->join('table2 s','sr.st_id=s.st_id'); 
if($conn!='')
{
    $this->db->where($conn);
}
if($identity!='')
{
    $where = "(s.student_id = '$identity' OR s.name LIKE '%$identity%')";
    $this->db->where($where);
}
if($duplicate != '')
{
  $this->db->having('COUNT("sr.st_id")>1');
  $this->db->group_by('sr.st_id');          
}
if($limit_row!='')
{
    $this->db->limit($limit_row,$starting);
}
$query = $this->db->get();
var_dump($this->db->last_query($query));exit;
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: It shows only one record, I want to show all.I mean how many duplicates are from a record